# How to add a User model validation to block certain email domains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby-on-rails-3, activemodel

I would like to have a list of email domains that are validated against to prevent from registering on my app.

10minutemail.com, yopmail.com, mail.com, mail.ru etc...

I have a list of domains in my user model like so:

```
BAD_DOMAINS = [/10minutemail.com/, /yopmail.com/, /mail/
```

I would like to add a User validates on the email field to add an error if the user is registering with one of these domains.

```
BAD_DOMAINS.each { |rule| return true if !domain.match(rule).nil? }
```

I have that regex working, but how do I add that as a validates? I tried this:

```
validates :email, :format => { : exclusion => BAD_DOMAINS,
        :message => "%{value} no good." }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to combine all of your separate regular expressions into a singular one, but you might find it's easier to do that if you have a list of strings instead of a list of regular expressions:

```
EXCLUSION_DOMAINS = %w[
  example.com
  test.com
  asdf.com
]

EXCLUSION_REGEXP = Regexp.new('(?:' + EXCLUSION_DOMAINS.collect { |d| Regexp.escape(d) }.join('|') + ')$')
```

You'll want to ensure that things don't match this, so it's a little different to use:

```
validates :email,
  :format => {
    :with => VALID_EMAIL_REGEXP,
    :without => EXCLUSION_REGEXP,
    :message => "%{value} no good."
  }
```

You should use some kind of valid email tester as well to be sure the address is plausible. It's expressed here as `VALID_EMAIL_REGEXP` which is some kind of email validator regular expression. Try and use an RFC compliant one if you do that.

Comment: Thanks ... There isn't a way to validate the email is valid with? validates :email, :presence => true, :email => true

Comment: It seems you have to split this validator in tow parts as long as you cannot use both :with and :without.